# How do I check if a command/variable contains \par?

Tags: conditionals

So the following problem:

If there is a command defined like this: 
`\newcommand{\a}{Michael \par Michael@mail.de \par 01234556}`, when I want to compile `\a`, it does exactly that.

However, if there is command defined like this:
`\newcommand{\b}{Michael}` and when I want to compile `\b`, it should write:

```
Michael

???        
???
```

Or some filler like "???" which should fill 2 extra lines. How do I do that?

Comment: while it is possible to dissect the `\par` a more normal interface would be to have input `\name{Michael}` .. `\email{x@y}` ... `phone{123}`  and have `\email` and `\phone` default to `??` if the commands are not used to supply real values.

Answer (score 1):

I have interprested the OP's question in a more sophisticated way that what, on the surface, would seem to be satisfied by a `\newcommand\b{michael\par???\par???\par}`.  Rather, I suspect what the OP really wants a macro to which he can pass 3-part or 1-part data as part of the argument, and have parts 2 & 3 defaulted.

Note `\a` is already pre-defined, so don't use it.  Further, you don't need two separate macros, you just need to look at what has been passed as the argument, and act accordingly.

As I have set it up, if either the 2nd or 3rd chuck of subdata are missing from the argument, a `???` will be output in its stead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\mya[1]{\myaaux#1\par\par\par\relax}
\long\def\myaaux#1\par#2\par#3\par#4\relax{#1\par\medskip%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax???\else#2\fi\par%
  \ifx\relax#3\relax???\else#3\fi\par%
}
\begin{document}
\mya{Michael \par Michael@mail.de \par 01234556}

\textit{versus}

\mya{Michael}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is an alternate interpretation of what the OP may actually desire.  The macro `\mya` is now defined to take and argument, `\AAA` or `\BBB` macro form is acceptable, and try to parse it into the multi-`\par` structure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\mya[1]{\expandafter\myaaux#1\par\par\par\relax}
\long\def\myaaux#1\par#2\par#3\par#4\relax{#1\par\medskip%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax???\else#2\fi\par%
  \ifx\relax#3\relax???\else#3\fi\par%
}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\AAA{Michael \par Michael@mail.de \par 01234556}
\newcommand\BBB{Michael}

\mya{\AAA}

\textit{versus}

\mya{\BBB}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry I HAVE TO use the predefined \a, and I can't alter the script where \a is defined.   I was thinking if there is something like: if a contains \par then ... ....

Comment: @supermonkeyyyyyy If you must overwrite the `\a`, then just change occurences in my example of `\mya` to `\a`.  You may need to change the `\newcommand\a{}` to `\renewcommand\a{}`, as well.

Comment: @supermonkeyyyyyy What are you meant to do if something you use relies on the original `\a`?

Comment: @supermonkeyyyyyy  Please look at the code of my alternate interpretation, to see if that better suits your need.